# How to get parent DIV width and set child DIV width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have attached html and a screenshot of my question.  I have a DIV container (DIV with `ID=ctl00_m_g_a788a965_7ee3_414f_bff9_2a561f8ca37d_ctl00_pnlParentContainer`) and inside the container I have 2 DIVs (one for the left column TITLE (DIV `ID=dvTitles`) and the other for the right column MONTH (DIV `ID=dvMilestones`).  The TITLE column width will always be static (i.e. 135px, which is set on a TD inside the DIV).  The right div will grow dynamically (i.e. to show MAY, JUNE, JULY months).

Notice I have float left on the 2 divs and I have overflow set to auto on the right div.  The parent div has a set width.  I need the interior right div to include a horizontal scroll bar when the max width has been reached.

I am not sure how to set the width and on what div to get this to work.  The outer most div is the width I need (I believe).  DIV `id=WebPartctl00_m_g_a788a965_7ee3_414f_bff9_2a561f8ca37d`

I hope that makes sense.  Thanks for any help provided.  Not sure if I can do this all with css or jquery.

```
<div WebPartID="a788a965-7ee3-414f-bff9-2a561f8ca37d" HasPers="false" id="WebPartctl00_m_g_a788a965_7ee3_414f_bff9_2a561f8ca37d" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody ms-wpContentDivSpace" allowDelete="false" allowExport="false" style="" >
<div id="ctl00_m_g_a788a965_7ee3_414f_bff9_2a561f8ca37d">               
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dvMilestones").scrollTo($(".scrollTo").index());       
        });
    </script>
    <div id="ctl00_m_g_a788a965_7ee3_414f_bff9_2a561f8ca37d_ctl00_pnlParentContainer" class="milestoneTracker">                        
        <div id="dvTitles" style="float:left">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top; width:135px;">                                
                        <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">                
                            <tr>                                                       
                                <td style="border:0">Title</td>                            
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td style="border:0">&nbsp;</td></tr>  
                            <tr class="rowOdd">                           
                                <td style="border:0">
                                    <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="http://amc/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=134d94b6-a11c-4f5c-9ee2-3595cf8f5707&amp;ID=59&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0102004D5169009FA72B4287B37C512D83E740" onclick="EditLink2(this,ctx.ctxId);return false;" target="_self">Lou Milestone Event 1</a>                            
                                </td>                       
                            </tr>                                                 
                            <tr class="rowEven">                           
                                <td style="border:0">
                                    <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="http://amc/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=134d94b6-a11c-4f5c-9ee2-3595cf8f5707&amp;ID=60&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0102004D5169009FA72B4287B37C512D83E740" onclick="EditLink2(this,ctx.ctxId);return false;" target="_self">Lou Milestone Event 2</a>                            
                                </td>                       
                            </tr>                                                 
                            <tr class="rowOdd">                           
                                <td style="border:0">
                                    <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="http://amc/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=134d94b6-a11c-4f5c-9ee2-3595cf8f5707&amp;ID=61&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0102004D5169009FA72B4287B37C512D83E740" onclick="EditLink2(this,ctx.ctxId);return false;" target="_self">Lou Milestone Event 3</a>                            
                                </td>                       
                            </tr>                                                 
                            <tr class="rowEven">                           
                                <td style="border:0">
                                    <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="http://amc/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=134d94b6-a11c-4f5c-9ee2-3595cf8f5707&amp;ID=62&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0102004D5169009FA72B4287B37C512D83E740" onclick="EditLink2(this,ctx.ctxId);return false;" target="_self">Lou Milestone Event 4</a>                            
                                </td>                       
                            </tr>                                                 
                            <tr class="rowOdd">                           
                                <td style="border:0">
                                    <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="http://amc/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=134d94b6-a11c-4f5c-9ee2-3595cf8f5707&amp;ID=63&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0102004D5169009FA72B4287B37C512D83E740" onclick="EditLink2(this,ctx.ctxId);return false;" target="_self">Lou Milestone Event 5</a>                            
                                </td>                       
                            </tr>                                                 
                            <tr class="rowEven">                           
                                <td style="border:0">
                                    <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="http://amc/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=134d94b6-a11c-4f5c-9ee2-3595cf8f5707&amp;ID=64&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0102004D5169009FA72B4287B37C512D83E740" onclick="EditLink2(this,ctx.ctxId);return false;" target="_self">Lou Milestone Event 6</a>                            
                                </td>                       
                            </tr>                                                 
                        </table>                              
                    </td>    
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="dvMilestones" style="float:left; overflow:auto; width:450px;"> 
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>                        
                    <td style="vertical-align:top;">   
                        <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="175px">        
                            <tr>         
                                <td id="ctl00_m_g_a788a965_7ee3_414f_bff9_2a561f8ca37d_ctl00_rptMilestoneDate_ctl00_monthTD" style="border:0" align="center" colspan="5">
                                    May&nbsp;2011                                           
                                    <tr>                                                                                                
                                        <td align="center" >1</td>                                                    
                                        <td align="center" >8</td>                                                    
                                        <td align="center" >15</td>
                                        <td align="center" >22</td>                                                    
                                        <td align="center" >29</td>                                                                                            
                                    </tr>                                                                                                
                                    <tr class="rowOdd">                                                        
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;                                                                                                                          
                                            <img src="/_layouts/images/GaryDiamond.jpg" />                                                             
                                            <img src="/_layouts/images/CheckMark.jpg" />                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                        </td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                  
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                                                           
                                    </tr>                                                                                                                                                          
                                    <tr class="rowEven">                                                        
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                            <img src="/_layouts/images/CheckMark.jpg" />                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                            <img src="/_layouts/images/GaryDiamond.jpg" />
                                        </td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                                                           
                                    </tr>                                                                                                                                                          
                                    <tr class="rowOdd">                                                        
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;                                                   
                                            <img src="/_layouts/images/CheckMark.jpg" />                                                                                                                                      
                                            <img src="/_layouts/images/GaryDiamond.jpg" />                                                             
                                        </td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                                                          
                                    </tr>                                                                                                                                                          
                                    <tr class="rowEven">
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;                                                   
                                            <img src="/_layouts/images/CheckMark.jpg" />                                                                                                                                      
                                            <img src="/_layouts/images/GaryDiamond.jpg" />                                                             
                                        </td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                                                          
                                    </tr>                                                                                                                                                          
                                    <tr class="rowOdd">                                                        
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;                                                   
                                            <img src="/_layouts/images/CheckMark.jpg" />                                                                                                                                      
                                            <img src="/_layouts/images/GaryDiamond.jpg" />                                                             
                                        </td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                   
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                                                          
                                    </tr>                                                                                                                                                         
                                    <tr class="rowEven">
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;                                                   
                                            <img src="/_layouts/images/CheckMark.jpg" />                                                                                                                                      
                                            <img src="/_layouts/images/GaryDiamond.jpg" />                                                             
                                        </td>                                                       
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                       
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                       
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                       
                                        <td align="center" style="width:100px!important; border:0">&nbsp;</td>                                                                                                                                                           
                                    </tr>                                                                                                                                  
                                </td>                       
                            </tr>        
                        </table>
                    </td>                                    
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can get the width of elements using `width()` in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips provided.  I ended up using a table on the left side and wrapped my table on the right side with a DIV to make it scrollable on the x axis.  I ended up using jquery to set widths accordingly.  I probably did not provide enough detail about my problem.

Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, when the table inside `dvMilestones` grows, the `dvMilestones` shows a scroll (I tested it, putting `width="800"` in the table, and the scroll appears).

Surely you didn't test it with a long width.

Hope this helps. Cheers